# How to link to a class with selective text in ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml

So, I'm trying to make a link which has a class and some text with the given link. Here's the code -

```
= link_to((session[:request_id] ? 'Save & Exit': 'Exit'), "/account/#{@name}", :id => 'cancel-application', :class => "cancel-application")
```

What I want is that I get a link to this class called "cancel-application", which is actually a small cancel image. In front of it, I want to get "Save & Exit" or "Exit" depending on the session. The "Save & Exit" or "Exit" button should also be linked. Something like this -

[cancel button] "Exit"  (where both link to the same place)

Right now, what this code does, is put the image and the text on top of each other, which makes sense. So, what I thought of doing was put the session id in a variable and then put it after the link like this -

```
= @exit_text = session[:request_id] ? 'Save & Exit': 'Exit'
= link_to("/account/#{@name}", :id => 'cancel-application', :class => "cancel-application") @exit_text
```

This doesn't work. I was wondering how I could do something like that.

EDIT - I found a solution, although I feel there can be better ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can still do this with one link:

```
= link_to "/store/#{@name}", :id => 'cancel-application' do
  .cancel-application
  = session[:request_id] ? 'Save & Exit' : 'Exit'
```

`link_to` can accept the block which is captured to build link's inner html. When you pass the block, you do not pass links label.

Answer (score 0):

I just used two `link_to`. I guess there's no way to do it in one `link_to`:

```
 = link_to("", "/account/#{@name}", :id => 'cancel-application', :class => "cancel-application")

 = link_to((session[:request_id] ? 'Save & Exit': 'Exit'), "/account/#{@name}", :id => 'cancel-application')
```

Comment: You don't need to put "[Solved]" in the answer. Just select it as the accepted answer once SO says it's OK.

Comment: In the question you told that those links are point to the same direction, your solution contains two different paths. Is this correct?

Comment: @BroiSatse no they are intended to point to the same direction.